# button to toggle between 2 layouts is not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My idea is to provide a switch which toggles between a bootstrap carousel and cards, basically one of them will be visible when the the button is pressed(one will be invisible at all times). First I'm trying to make my carousel(existing) invisible, however my javascript code isn't working. I'm pretty new to javascript, I hope I'm not making some stupid mistake. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```js
function change(toggles) {
  var which = document.getElementById("format1");
  if (toggles.value == "yes") {
    format1.style.display = "block";
    toggles.value = "no";
  } else {
    toggles.value = "yes";
  }
};
```

```html
<div class=" container container1">
  <br>
  <div class="card card-body" id="card-mine">
    <span>[...]</span>
  </div>

  <div id="format1">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom: 3%;">
        [...]
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->

        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: green">
          [...]
        </div>

        <!-- Slide Five - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #8D6E63">
          [...]
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        </a>
      </div>

      <br>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button id="toggles" class="button toggles" value="yes" onclick="change(this)">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe change `format1.style.display` to `which.style.display`?

Comment: @obe It didn't work.

Comment: what happens exactly? what errors do you see in the dev console?

Comment: @obe ```GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico 404 (NOT FOUND)``` - The Error

Comment: this message is not relevant to your problem. sorry, i don't know. if you make a simple program that reproduces this in a https://jsfiddle.net/ of something then i'll have another look.

Comment: how are you setting up the onclick listener?

Comment: @henokg ```<button id="toggles" class="button toggles" value="yes" onclick="change(this)">Click</button>``` This is given at the end in ```My HTML```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and the problem is in the logic, you are setting it to visible on the first `if` block, it was suppose to be invisible.

```
  if (toggles.value == "yes") {
    which.style.display = "none";
    toggles.value = "no";
  } else {
    toggles.value = "yes";
    which.style.display = "block";
  }
```

Comment: if (toggles.value == "yes") { else { toggles.value = "yes";} ???

Comment: yes, in order to toggle the visibility of the element, it has to be switched